# how to achieve Value inheritance of DP in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

how to achieve Value inheritance of DP in silverlight, or is there any way to share a property value of parent with children, Datacontext cant be shared in my case.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508763/property-value-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to write code to handle this yourself.

Some existing API types such as the `UIElement`->`FrameworkElement`->`Control` heirarchy do implement some form of "value inheritance" such as `FontFamily` etc.  However it's code inside these types which handles this, there is no general mechanism present to support the concept.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this little differently, I have tried to set Binding for property to it's parent's same property in the constructor. So after the object is created if you set an explicit value, binding will be removed. Otherwise it is bound to Parent's x property.