# How to set the default color theme of an app in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to set the default color of an application?

The problem is I have custom backgrounds in my app. If I have the white theme selected it looks nice. When I select the dark theme I cannot read it.

Is there a way to set it for the whole application e.g. that it should be white, whatever the phone default theme is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your own color resources and use them on your elements where necessary. [Here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/how-to-define-and-reuse-resources-in-wp7) is an example how to do this. Defining one "default color" for the whole application is not possible as far as I know. It would be a rather obscure setting. Maybe [property value inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508763/property-value-inheritance) comes close to what you mean.

By the way: please don't design overly bright applications which ignore my dark theme. It hurts my eyes.