# ContentControl (CheckBox) does not inherit Foreground

Tags: xaml, silverlight

It looks like the [`CheckBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox(v=vs.95).aspx) control does not inherit its `Foreground` property:

```
<UserControl Foreground="Orange">
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- this shows as black - no inheritance -->
        <CheckBox Content="foo" />

        <!-- this shows as turquoise -->
        <CheckBox Foreground="Turquoise" Content="bar" />

        <!-- but this shows as orange - inheritance works here -->
        <TextBlock Text="baz" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

[image: Screenshot -- "foo" is black, "bar" is turquoise, "baz" is orange]

What's the reason for this, and what is the best workaround?

**Edit** @helb suggested the reason is the [default style, which sets the Foreground to black](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278078%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  I don't think this explains it, though: if you override that style and remove the line - `<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>` - the behavior stays the same.

Comment: Maybe because the CheckBox style defines the Foreground property explicitly. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278078%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: @helb I'm not sure that explains it - see my edit (FWIW I posted my own tentative answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could find is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which may be an explanation:

> Property value inheritance behavior is not globally enabled for all dependency properties, because the calculation time for inheritance does have some performance impact. Property value inheritance is typically only enabled for properties where a particular scenario suggests that property value inheritance is appropriate.

So maybe they decided not to apply Foreground inheritance to ContentControls, for performance reasons.  Would be nice to be able to confirm this, though.  ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509222/1001985) claims to have used reflector to uncover an opaque hex value, in the internal DP registration, that may have something to do with it.)

This is one possible workaround (seems adequate, I guess):

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=Foreground}" />
</Style>
```

**Edit**

More evidence for the "ContentControl doesn't inherit Foreground" theory: Button *does not* inherit; ComboBox *does* inherit.

Comment: Yea or pull out the ContentPresenter in the style template and substitute it with a TextBlock that has Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" might do it also. I ran into issues with ContentPresenter not inheriting the way you might hope before like that.

Comment: @ChrisW. thanks, I will try that too -- seems better from a performance standpoint.  I will be surprised if it does work though because, since Foreground does not get inherited through CheckBox, wouldn't the TextBlock just get the default (black) value?

Comment: @ChrisW. yep, same problem.  Would be nice if this stuff was at least documented somewhere. :-P

Comment: Yea but then we'd never get a chance to have these nice chats ;)

Comment: @ChrisW. that is true ... so, how is the weather there in Kansas?

Comment: Eh friggin cold, on that note let me know if you ever want a hand making those apps you've been pumping out more 'pretty' :D

Comment: shot ya an email yesterday